# Getting undefined reference error to stdout, stderr while compiling using x86 tool chain of Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, digital-certificate, android-ndk-r7

I am trying to compile one of the native libraries libdigcert using Android NDK toolchain.

If I use arm toolchain everything works fine and if I link this library to my executable I dont get any linker errors.

If I use x86 toolchain, then I get linker errors which are showing undefined reference to stdout , stderr etc.

I used nm to read the difference between both .a files (arm and x86), and I see that, the x86 file has stdout undefined, while arm .a does not even mention stdout symbol.

Can anyone point me to what I am missing here?

Comment: did you figure this one out?